# How to Get Started Implementing Dps Payment Express Payment Gateway in PHP?

Tags: php, web, payment-gateway

I have a created a website in which I want to use the online payment procedure Dps Payment Express Payment gateway.

However, I don't know how to go about using it. The website runs on PHP. Does anyone know of any tutorials or example code that shows how to use this system under PHP?

Comment: how does online payment procedure on a php-based website get the "iphone" tag?

Comment: @ocdcoder - I edited the tags from iPhone to php etc

Comment: I think he is talking about this gateway http://www.paymentexpress.com/index.html

Answer (score 0):

They have sample code on their website:

[PX Pay](http://www.paymentexpress.com/technical_resources/ecommerce_hosted/pxpay.html)
[PX Access](http://www.paymentexpress.com/technical_resources/ecommerce_hosted/pxaccess.html)